# Can't declare variable in Firebird 2.5, why?

Tags: variables, firebird, declaration, firebird2.5

I have a one line query:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE var_SecondsOfTime INTEGER;
```

But after running the query I am getting this message:

> Engine Error (code = 335544569):
>   Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code =
>   -104. Token unknown - line 1, column 9. VARIABLE.
>
> SQL Error (code = -104): Invalid
>   token.

I've looked everywhere on the Internet and all examples showing the same declaration style which I am using.

What is wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring your variable?? stored procedure, or where? 
from where are you executing your code, isql? other?

Comment: @jachguate: I am declaring it in a plain query, which is executed by FirebirdMaestro application. I guess it connects to the DB via isql. As I said it is one line query, nothing more. No stored procedure, nothing. Just this line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebird 2.5 supports execution of code blocks surrounded by a **[execute block](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html)** statement, try this:

```
set term ^ ;

EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS
   DECLARE VARIABLE var_SecondsOfTime INTEGER;

BEGIN
  SELECT 1 from RDB$DATABASE into var_SecondsOfTime ;
END
^

set term ; ^
```

I issued the select because I'm pretty sure it is not possible to execute an empty block, try this by yourself removing the select.

[image: isql running the block]

**Edit**
My original select was invalid for a block, I added the into clause to collect the result.  I never used firebird maestro, but it now works perfectly on isql, as shown.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, the error which I have after executing your code is this: Engine Error (code = 335544569):
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, column 1.
END.

SQL Error (code = -104):
Invalid token.  Maybe there is something wrong with Firebird Maestro..?

Comment: @Wodzu the block was missing a into clause.  I personally never used firebird maestro, so I don't know if it requires a different terminator, I surrounded the block on a couple of set term clauses just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your intereest, I'll check your updated answer shortly and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: The second set term needs the semi colon before the carat..   `set term  ;^ `   .

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
set term ^ ;

EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS
   DECLARE VARIABLE var_SecondsOfTime INTEGER;

BEGIN
  SELECT  1 from RDB$DATABASE  into :var_SecondsOfTime ;
END^

set term  ;^
```

The second set term needs the semi colon before the carat.